# Adobe Media Server - How to publish and play live stream videos using Android

Tags: android, flash, video, rtmp, adobe-media-server

I'm developing an Android App, that will have videos streamed from Adobe Media Server using RTMPS, and also I need to publish these to AMS.

I've got this link below for:

1. Downstream:

[Live Stream videos from Adobe Media Server](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/)

Nothing for publishing upstream. Please suggest, how to proceed with Native Android App.

Comment: **@Arvind** you should [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40239762/edit) the question with your extra details. Have you bought an Adobe Media Server account? Is there anything in the [**`manual`**](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/stream-live-media-http.html) that is not working? Also check [**Adobe help**](https://helpx.adobe.com/search.html#q=adobe%20media%20server&t=All&sort=relevancy&CommonProduct=Adobe%20Media%20Server). Not clear what the **specific** issue is. Not even a question mark in this post (okay, you didn't write it but you can improve it)...

Answer (score 1):

I do this last year by reading [Android Live Streaming courtesy of JavaCV and FFMPEG](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/) post. But now, I think You can use [Yasea](https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea) library.It is an Android streaming client. It encodes YUV and PCM data from camera and microphone to H.264/AAC, encapsulates in FLV and transmits over RTMP.